# SLF4J Android 1.7.+ not logging on Logcat

Tags: android, slf4j, logcat, android-logcat, slf4j-android

In my build.gradle , the logcat is visible when

```
debugCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1'
```

However when the version is updated  , there is logcat

```
debugCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.14'
```

I am stuck with 1.6.1-RC1 version. Why the newer versions of slf4j-android:1.7.x are not logged in the logcat ?

I use SLF4J in the code like this

```
private static final Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(TAG);
LOG.debug("variable = {}", var);
```

**References**

http://www.slf4j.org/android/

http://www.slf4j.org/news.html ( changelog )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-314 gave me the answer .

To see the logs on "slf4j-android:1.7.x" , using Android setprop is the official approach. 
 The downside of this approach is that you have to select the TAG but cannot show all logs . For example in the logcat :

```
app_package D/TAG1: blabla
app_package D/TAG2: lorem ipsum
```

In the terminal , enter

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.TAG1 VERBOSE
```

I will only display TAG1 and no the others TAGs . I wonder if it is possible to print all other Tags.

For now , I think I will stick with 1.6.1-RC1 version

Answer (score 1):

i just looked at the [source code of AndroidLoggerAdapter.java](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-android/src/main/java/org/slf4j/impl/AndroidLoggerAdapter.java) The code 1.7.+ now uses `if isLoggable(priority)` before every logging statement while the 1.6.+ just logged without asking.

It is an android default feature that 
`if (Log.isLoggable("MY_TAG", Log.VERBOSE))` always return false while 
`Log.v("MY_TAG", "Here's a log message")` still works

This explains why org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.14 does not work anymore.

Maybe this helps to cope with the new version: [Android logging levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126815/android-logging-levels)

I am using http://github.com/lp0/slf4j-android an alternative implementation that uses a config file to enable/disable config settings