# Log.isLoggable problems with android 6.0 (Marshmallow / api 23 )

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using android Log.isLoggable api in order to determine whether my custom log tag is on and should I log. (I'm setting property using setprop log.tag. on the device). 
As far as Docs says, and as I'm familiar with older version, it should return true if the log level in the property is equal or high than the one I'm checking in my code. 
This works fine for Lollipop and below (api 22) it's seems that something was changed in Marshmallow, as I encounter inconsistency and buggy behavior, playing with the values of the tag will result sometimes with the wrong value returned from isLogabble(), for instance a concrete scenario I did a check in code :

```
 boolean shouldLog = Log.isLoggable("mytag", Log.DEBUG);
 Log.d("debug", "shouldLog = " + shouldLog);
```

- I set log.tag.mytag value to some arbitrary string
- launch my app, and see the isLoggable = false, that's OK
- then I change log.tag.mytag to VERBOSE
- launch my app, isLoggable still false , that's not OK! should be true now

same scenario is not reproducible at Lollipop and didn't encounter any other misbehaviors. 
Any suggestions, do I miss something here?

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126815/android-logging-levels) helps?

Comment: @IshitaSinha , I'm setting prop using adb shell setprop, also as I've mentioned it's working as expected with Lollipop, so it's not seems like the problem there