# How do I run a command against the Android emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, assert

I am trying to enable assertions (the keyword, not the junit methods) in my android project.

What I've tried so far:
I added a command line argument, -ea, in Eclipse (Indigo) under Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs where I edit the only JRE listed (see two images below). 
[image: List of installed JREs]

[image: Default VM Arguments]

That didn't work... I assume because this applies to my default JVM, not the dalvik VM.

I found a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043681/better-way-to-do-debug-only-assert-code) that suggested running a command against the emulator or device (I am most interested in the emulator) to enable assertions. But I don't understand what that means. The command is:

```
adb shell setprop debug.assert 1
```

So my question is, how do I run a command against the emulator (using a Mac, if that's relevant)?

Many thanks!

Comment: @JohnGiotta Same as what? Maybe it would help if I framed this as a newbie question. When I hear "run command x against y", I simply don't know what that means.

Comment: I didn't realize you couldn't find where adb was located on your machine. No, I thought you expected the command to be different on a Mac... which it isn't, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is, how do I run a command against the emulator

Open up a Terminal window (or your preferred equivalent, like iTerm), and type in the command at the command line. If you have not done so already, you need to add `$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools` to your `PATH`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you have unZIPped the SDK on your machine.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare. I had to look up [how to add a directory to the PATH variable for mac](http://keito.me/tutorials/macosx_path) (that's how green I am). But after following your suggestions, I am able to get assertion errors!

Answer (score 0):

First at all is necessary know the devices connected:

```
adb devices
```

And then select the desired device name and type:

```
adb -s <device-name> shell
```

At this point you are connected to the device shell and could execute commands.

Regards.