# In Navigation Drawer, getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-theme

I am trying to make the Navigation drawer in my welcome page after login.  But

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

throws Null pointer exception. In logcat, I got the message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.samvardhan.org.vaccinationinfo.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:170)
```

I am using

Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
. I tried to change the theme to

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"

This also didn't worked. I want to use

> Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

How to solve this issue. This

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

should not give me null value. This getActionBar() is giving me null. How could I solve this one with same theme.

Comment: If there is no action bar then `getActionBar()` returns null... I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Hope you need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786011/how-to-fix-getactionbar-method-may-produce-java-lang-nullpointerexception

Comment: @paudel.saulav are you setting any view to action bar ?? getSupportAction.setActionView(<give you view > e.g toolbar> )

Comment: @cricket_007, I am trying to make navigation drawer. there I need to getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

in your `Styles` and make sure you've added The `Toolbar` in your `XML`:

**Example:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

And of course, in your `OnCreate`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And use this for `AppCompat`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

That should solve your problem.