# Are asserts available on Android?

Tags: android

Are asserts available on Android? I have:

```
assert(null);
```

It does nothing and I am in the debug mode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, they are available.

They are disabled in emulator by default. You will need to add `-shell -prop debug.assert=1` command line parameters to Additional Emulator Command Line Options at the run configuration you're using to run your app.

[image: Assertions in eclipse]

The other thing you should be aware of is that your application installed on a device will not take into account assertions - they will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much for talking the time. I have added "-shell -prop debug.assert=1" to the "Additional Emulator Command Line Options". Still no asserts? I'm using Eclipse Indigo with Android SDK 14.

Comment: try the code: `assert false : Log.e("!! Assertion works !!", "");` and see if this message appears in LogCat.

Comment: It doesn't. Thanks anyways. I'll keep looking.

Comment: That's strange. Make sure you're starting your app with this run configuration on **emulator**. Put the assertion code into the `onCreate()` method of the activity which certainly starts.

Comment: @a.ch. doesn't seem to work for me either, could you post a screenshot of how your screen looks like on hitting `assert false` ?

Comment: I just get the following stacktrace:
E/AndroidRuntime(287): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(287): java.lang.AssertionError: 24 
E/AndroidRuntime(287): at a.ch.MainApp.onCreate(MainApp.java:25) 
E/AndroidRuntime(287): at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969) 
E/AndroidRuntime(287): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4244)

Answer (score 0):

Currently eclipse suggests the following:

Assertions are unreliable. Use BuildConfig.DEBUG conditional checks instead.

Issue Explanation:

Assertions are not checked at runtime. There are ways to request that they be used by Dalvik (adb shell setprop debug.assert 1), but the property is ignored in many places and can not be relied upon. Instead, perform conditional checking inside if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { } blocks. That constant is a static final boolean which is true in debug builds and false in release builds, and the Java compiler completely removes all code inside the if-body from the app.

For example, you can replace

```
assert speed > 0
```

with

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && !(speed > 0)) { throw new AssertionError(); }
```

(Note: This lint check does not flag assertions purely asserting nullness or non-nullness; these are typically more intended for tools usage than runtime checks.)

More Information: [[Issue 65183:    Intellij/Studio doesn't activate asserts when running Android code in debug mode](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65183)]OK

Answer (score -3):

you can just use Android JUnit Assert:

```
Assert.assertTrue(false);
```

Comment: it requires provide `junit` library dependency to app itself, so it doesn't sound like good solution