# The purpose of Assertation and Assert filter in LogCat how it can be useful and why it is different from Log.e()?

Tags: java, android, logcat, assert, android-testing

I'm curious I've never seen in my `LogCat` any messages marked as `Assert`. I have read documentation as [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/Assert.html), but actually I didn't get the purpose of it and how it can be useful? I got that it throws errors, but why it is different with for example `Log.e()`. Can anyone tell me or point at some useful article about the purpose of it and give some small example? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.util.Log.ASSERT` log level is something you see when you use the one of the [`wtf()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#wtf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) logging methods.

It generally means "assertion failure" i.e. a programming error with certain assumptions not being true and it's best to terminate the program immediately.

`junit.framework.Assert` you linked to is another mechanism for expressing assertions. On failure, an [`AssertionFailedError`](http://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/AssertionFailedError.html) will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

may be [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164145/are-asserts-available-on-android) help for you.

They are disabled in emulator by default. You will need to add -shell -prop debug.assert=1 command line parameters to Additional Emulator Command Line Options at the run configuration you're using to run your app.

Comment: I saw that link, thanks. But I'm not about how to switch it on/off, but how I can use it or what it does actually.