# Assertions Android Programming

Tags: android, assertions

Can you use assertions in android programming? If so how do you enable it in eclipse?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298909/java-assertions-underused for reasons why assertions are unpopular in Java in general, let alone in Android

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176441/how-to-use-assert-in-android for tip how to enable assertions in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question was if it is possible... Yes it is possible but I go along with CommonsWare that asserions should be avoided.

Anyway see [Can I use assert on Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364910/can-i-use-assert-on-android-devices) for how to use Assertions on Android