# How to enable assertions in Eclipse v3.7.2

Tags: android, eclipse, assert

I can't seem to get assertions working in my eclipse android project.  I have followed the directions at [this site](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/EclipseIntroduction.html#assertions)

But I still can't get them to work.  My code looks like:

```
assert(false) : "PROGRAM ERROR - invalid dialog call";
```

any ideas?

Comment: FYI I have added '-ea' to 'Default VM Arguments' in Window/preferences/java/editor/installed JREs' for the selected Installed JRE

Comment: DalvikVM skips assertions by default, you can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364910/can-i-use-assert-on-android-devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dalvik VM ignores Java assertions by default. To enable that, one must change `debug.assert` property, e.g by invoking command in command line:

```
adb shell setprop debug.assert 1
```

Please note that you have to restart VM after that (force stop application: Settings->Apps->click on the app->Force stop).

Please also note that the setting is not persistent (assertions will be disabled again after phone reboot). However on rooted phones there's a way to make it persistent by putting `/data/local.prop` file containing line

```
debug.assert=1
```

Comment: Is this the same if I just want them to work on the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

What language are you expecting to use with the above?

I would try:

```
assertTrue("Expected true", true);

assertFalse("Expected false", true);

assertEquals("Expected equal", "same", "same");
```

Junit:

[junit-docs/junit/framework/Assert.html](http://www.cs.laurentian.ca/badams/c2006/junit-docs/junit/framework/Assert.html)

Comment: java - for use with the android emulator.