# Code assertion in android

Tags: android, assertions

Are the code assertions really run in Android for the release builds? Assertion failures are not reported by my code. It leads to crashes. Is there a way to turn on Assertions for release mode?

Comment: Assertions are used to find programming errors. They are not* part of the logic of a program. The an assertion failed, you "failed at programming" … ;-) (* read = _must not be_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `junit.framework.Assert` instead of the Java `assert` keyword (which gets stripped by Dalvik) should do the trick.

If you insist on using the `assert` keyword, there are various [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364910/can-i-use-assert-on-android-devices/5563637#5563637).

Answer (score 0):

Even on Java assert is only for debug purpose, not being guaranteed to work on releases.