# assert statement doesn't work in Android?

Tags: java, android, assert

In the following code, the assert statement seems to be ignored:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    runTest();
}

private void runTest() 
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    Log.d("Test", "Start");     
    assert a == b : "assertion failed";
    Log.d("Test", "End");       
}
}
```

The output is simply: 
    04-30 12:48:51.078: D/Test(29964): Start 
    04-30 12:48:51.078: D/Test(29964): End

There is no "assertion failed" there.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I use assert on Android devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2364910/1856738)

Comment: adb shell setprop debug.assert 1