# Error on picking contacts with no Photo Id/ Display Picture

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am accessing a contact's name, number and photo. Everything is working fine but if a contact does not have any photo assigned to it, then the app is throwing an error and force closing.
I have the three methods for retrieving name,number and photo and I have used this data to set 2 editTexts and an imageView.

```
private void retrieveContactPhoto() {

    Bitmap photo = null;

    try {


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.callerPic);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

        if (inputStream != null) {
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            //  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.callerPic);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
        if (inputStream == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No profile pic found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        assert inputStream != null;
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void retrieveContactNumber() {

    String contactNumber = null;

    // getting contacts ID
    Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
            null, null, null);

    if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

        contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    }

    cursorID.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

    // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
    Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

            new String[]{contactID},
            null);

    if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
        contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }

    cursorPhone.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
    EditText callerNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.callerNum);
    callerNum.setText(contactNumber);
}

private void retrieveContactName() {

    String contactName = null;

    // querying contact data store
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriContact, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        // DISPLAY_NAME = The display name for the contact.
        // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =   An indicator of whether this contact has at least one phone number.

        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    cursor.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact Name: " + contactName);
    EditText callerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.callerName);
    callerName.setText(contactName);
}
```

So, my question is how to know whether a contact has a display picture or not, so that I can put a default image if there is no image? Thanks.

This is what happens when i pick a contact with name Act Broadband which has no photo or number;

Logcat:

```
06-20 22:48:32.267  31991-31991/fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro D/MainActivity3﹕ Contact Name: Act Broadband
06-20 22:48:32.275      551-749/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@34733acc (uid=10157 pid=31991)
06-20 22:48:32.316  31991-31991/fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro D/MainActivity3﹕ Contact ID: 2428
06-20 22:48:32.332  31991-31991/fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro D/MainActivity3﹕ Contact Phone Number: null
06-20 22:48:32.345  31991-31991/fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-20 22:48:32.346  31991-31991/fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro, PID: 31991
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/3789r3128-272B4D294943272D2927412D/2428 flg=0x1 }} to activity {fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro/fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro.MainActivity3}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3574)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
            at fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro.MainActivity3.retrieveContactPhoto(MainActivity3.java:124)
            at fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro.MainActivity3.onActivityResult(MainActivity3.java:74)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-20 22:48:32.348    551-12709/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 fake.call.sms.fakecallandsmspro/.MainActivity3
06-20 22:48:32.355    551-32557/? W/DropBoxManagerService﹕ Dropping: data_app_crash (1783 > 0 bytes)​
```

Comment: Logcat: http://txs.io/tB5b @M4rtini

Comment: NPE at line 124 (MainActivity3.java:124). So you know if there is a display picture or not by checking for null there.

Comment: `inputStream.close();` would fail if `inputStream`is null. Your assert statement is probably optimized away when running on the device

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364910/can-i-use-assert-on-android-devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change:

```java
        if (inputStream != null) {
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            //  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.callerPic);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
        if (inputStream == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No profile pic found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        assert inputStream != null;
        inputStream.close();
```

to

```java
        if (inputStream != null) {
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            //  ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.callerPic);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            inputStream.close();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No profile pic found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

This way you only call inputStream.close() if the inputStream is not null, without making the assertion. Also it is unnecessary to have `if(inputStream != null)` followed by `if(inputStream == null)`. So I have replaced the second 'if' statement with an 'else' statement.

Let me know if this helps!