# How do I enable assertions in CodenameOne using the IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, assert, codenameone

I like to use assertions in my code to catch bugs, but when I run my application, either in the simulator or on my Android phone, it ignores the assertions. I've looked through the Intellij IDE for a way to turn assertions on, but I can't find one. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with the IntelliJ plugin, I've filed it [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1739). I would assume editing the config file directly would help but this isn't the case so I can't find a workaround for now.

I've set the issue for a 3.4 deadline but I don't think we'll make it as the code freeze for 3.4 is 26th April 2016.

Device builds with asserts isn't something I tried but I did find [Can I use assert on Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364910/can-i-use-assert-on-android-devices)